# Where is the cookbook_file stored on Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra

I've created a very basic recipe:

```
cookbook_file "cookbook_test_file" do
  path "/tmp/test_file123"
  action [:create_if_missing, :create]
end
```

I've also created the cookbook_test_file file under files->default in my cookbook and added the recipe to the run book.

Everything works perfectly. 
The file gets propagated to the client. If the file is changed on the client then next time I run chef-client - the file gets updated as expected.  No issues.

However, I can't find cookbook_test_file anywhere on the chef server.I tried to fully qualify the default directory for the file as follows:
/usr/local/bin/cookbook_test_file but to no avail.

Where are these files stored on the chef server? ? I did not see it in the PostgreSQL database either.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you care? One of the effects of content-hash storage is that you can't change things on the server (since changing them changes their hash value), so even knowing where they are, you can't easily change them... and it's not easy to know where they are on account of the redirection layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only wanted to see if the file was uploaded correctly. Does it make any sense then to specify the full path and specify the file name only instead?

Answer (score 2):

They end up in the bookshelf file storage, but not in a directly useable way. Look in `/var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf`, the files are stored by content hash and have a CRC check prepended to them.

The file metadata is all stored in Postgres though, either in the sandbox data or the cookbook version.

Answer (score 0):

@coderanger has provided the answer you're looking for I think.

What I'd like to add is that knife can be used to check what was uploaded as part of a cookbook. The following example returns all the files in the apache2 cookbook:

```
$ knife cookbook show apache2 2.0.0 files -Fj
[
  {
    "name": "apache2_module_conf_generate.pl",
    "path": "files/default/apache2_module_conf_generate.pl",
    "checksum": "424ea6efb9da5b8cd9739f7f0f1fc9d5",
    "specificity": "default",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8889/file_store/checksums/424ea6efb9da5b8cd9739f7f0f1fc9d5"
  }
]
```